# What is the meaning of "hip book" in the conversation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english

"Hah, he only likes new books. Hip ones."  "Jane Eyre is a hip book!" What is the meaning of "hip book" in the conversation?

Comment: What did your research find?

Comment: "b : very fashionable : trendy" - Merriam-Webster

Answer (score 1):

As your research indicates, 'hip' here is an adjective that means 'fashionable' or 'trendy'. It's, ironically, not itself a particularly trendy word since the 80s, so it tends to be used these days somewhat sarcastically.

The book, Jane Eyre, considered a classic of English literature, is being described as a "hip" book by the second speaker, who is trying to imply that classics never go out of style.

Comment: +1 for the "As your research indicates...", haha